# Run databricks notebook from talend

Tags: databricks, talend

I'm wondering if it's possible to execute a Databricks notebook from Talend. I've tried searching for information, but it hasn't been easy to find. I have a Databricks notebook and I'm interested in triggering its execution directly from Talend. Is there a video tutorial or any other helpful resources available for this? Thank you.